# Samsung Gear S2 TTS Native API

Tags: service, voice-recognition, tizen, samsung-gear-s2

I'm following the tutorial:

[STT: Recognizing Speech](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tutorials/native-application/uix/stt)

I'm using STT API but I receive a STT_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED error when I
call create_stt_handle on Samsung Gear S2.
Is this API supported on this device or there's something wrong in calling this function on a service service_app_control :

```or-tag-here
   create_stt_handle()  {
                   int ret;
                   ret = stt_create(&stt);
                   if (STT_ERROR_NONE != ret)
                     {
                        dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, "create_stt_handle %#010x", ret);
                     }
                   if (STT_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED == ret)
                     {
                        dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, "create_stt_handle STT_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED");
                     }

       }


        void service_app_control(app_control_h app_control, void *data) {
            // Todo: add your code here.

            //create_stt_handle();

            //set_recognition_result_cb(stt);

            int error = register_accelerometer_callback(data);
            //dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, "after create %d", error);

            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stt need two feature tizen.org/feature/speech.recognition and tizen.org/feature/microphone

You need to check supported feature by systemapi as below.

https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/api-reference-2.3.1?redirect=https%3A//developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.1/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__CAPI__SYSTEM__SYSTEM__INFO__MODULE.html

```
#include "system_info.h"

bool stt_supported = false;
bool mic_supported = false;

system_info_get_platform_bool("http://tizen.org/feature/speech.recognition", &stt_supported);
system_info_get_platform_bool("http://tizen.org/feature/microphone", &mic_supported);

dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "supported = %d, %d", stt_supported ,mic_supported );
```

Maybe it can not support stt_supported.
Here is same question in tizen forum.

https://developer.tizen.org/forums/native-application-development/stt-support-on-real-gear-s2-not-emulator?tab=active